VS Code remote: environment variables not refreshed
VS Code Version: 1.90.2
OS Version:
Steps to Reproduce:
On WIndows OS
install OpenSSH Server
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse?tabs=gui
config administrators_authorized_keys
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement
On MacOS
config ~/.ssh/config
connect to Windows using VSCode remote
On Windows OS, install nvm with nvm-setup.zip
https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases
open powershell, test nvm command, it works
On MacOS VSCode
open powershell terminal, test nvm, it doesn't work
reload VSCode, test nvm, it doesn't work
quit VSCode and restart, it doesn't work
How can I make the environment variables working?
